# SQL Server dynamic pivot table with dates as columns using CTE as my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2016

So I have 36 month worth of data in my CTE, and the database is still active storing new data daily.

In my analysis, I just need 6 months worth of data from getdate()

So my question is that how do I make the month derived from calendar month the column of my table?

So for end of March 2022, this is the view that I should see:

| id | name | 10/01/21 | 11/01/21 | 12/01/21 | 01/01/22 | 02/01/22 | 03/01/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | Mary | 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Angelo | 1 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | Diane | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 6 |

So for the end of April 2022, this is the view that I should see:

| id | name | 11/01/21 | 12/01/21 | 01/01/22 | 02/01/22 | 03/01/2022 | 04/01/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | Mary | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Angelo | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | Diane | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 4 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Do you really want a 183 column table??

Comment: @Charlieface no, just last 6 months

Comment: @AaronBertrand MDY dates coming back to bite me, I thought it was showing every day in January. Why can't Americans just be normal like the rest of the world?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I absolutely hate the American format. And I live here, so I get it from both sides. My birthday is Feb 1 and when I submitted my daughter's paperwork for her birth certificate, I used `year-02-01` because I lived in a French-ish town in Rhode Island and didn't want to take any chances. They still messed it up.

Comment: @Charlieface Wait.... there are *normal* people in the world?  When did that happen?!  ;-)

Comment: Good grief.  How can anyone mess up yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: @SOS Welcome to the British Isles, where all normal people live. Everywhere else is the colonies :-)

Comment: @Charlieface - Heh, I *knew* they were hiding somewhere...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I apologize. I didn't think it mattered. Sorry again! I just added it right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a dynamic `PIVOT` without dynamic SQL. I find it's easiest to break it up into parts.

1. Get the last 6 months

   ```
    DECLARE @thisMonth date, @firstMonth date;
    SET @thisMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), 1);
    SET @firstMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, -5, @thisMonth);

    ;WITH m(m) AS 
    (
      SELECT @firstMonth
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m) FROM m
      WHERE m < @thisMonth
    )
    SELECT m FROM m ORDER BY m DESC;
   ```

   Output:

   | m |
   | --- |
   | 2022-03-01 |
   | 2022-02-01 |
   | 2022-01-01 |
   | 2021-12-01 |
   | 2021-11-01 |
   | 2021-10-01 |
2. Figure out what *manual* query you need. Given this sample data:

   ```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.JetSales
    (
      ID        int,
      Name      nvarchar(32),
      SalesDate date
    );

    INSERT dbo.JetSales(ID, Name, SalesDate) VALUES
    (1,N'John','20211005'),(1,N'John','20211016'),(1,N'John','20211031'),
    (2,N'Mary','20211007'),(2,N'Mary','20211013'),
    (3,N'Tank','20211009');
   ```

   I think you want a query like this (yes, you can accomplish this specific task with `PIVOT` too, but `PIVOT` doesn't cover some other scenarios, and it also requires pre-aggregation in this case... so I think conditional aggregation is better):

   ```
    SELECT ID, Name,  
      [10/01/2021] = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesDate >= '20211001' 
        AND SalesDate < '20211101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
      [11/01/2021] = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesDate >= '20211101' 
        AND SalesDate < '20211201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
      [12/01/2021] = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesDate >= '20211201' 
        AND SalesDate < '20220101' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
      [01/01/2022] = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesDate >= '20220101' 
        AND SalesDate < '20220201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
      [02/01/2022] = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesDate >= '20220201' 
        AND SalesDate < '20220301' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
      [03/01/2022] = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesDate >= '20220301' 
        AND SalesDate < '20220401' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM dbo.JetSales AS js GROUP BY ID, Name;
   ```
3. Which you can build as follows:

   ```
    DECLARE @thisMonth date, @firstMonth date;
    SET @thisMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), 1);
    SET @firstMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, -5, @thisMonth);

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ID, Name';

    ;WITH m(m) AS 
    (
      SELECT @firstMonth
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m) FROM m
      WHERE m < @thisMonth
    )
    SELECT @sql += N', 
    ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10), m, 101)) 
      + N' = SUM(CASE WHEN SalesDate >= ' 
      + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(8), m, 112), char(39)) + N' 
          AND SalesDate < '
      + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m), 112), char(39))
      + N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'
    FROM m;

    SET @sql += N'
    FROM dbo.JetSales AS js GROUP BY ID, Name;';

    SELECT @sql;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
   ```

Working example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=001742152944c499eccab66db4c5b3ce)

If you really want to use `PIVOT` explicitly, you can, it's just a lot more cumbersome. Here's the query you want to end up with:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT ID, Name, m = CONVERT(char(10), 
      DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(SalesDate), Month(SalesDate), 1), 101)
  FROM dbo.JetSales
  WHERE SalesDate >= @firstMonth
),
agg AS
(
  SELECT ID, Name, m, c = COUNT(*)
  FROM src GROUP BY ID, Name, m
)
SELECT ID, Name,
  [10/01/2021] = COALESCE([10/01/2021], 0),
  [11/01/2021] = COALESCE([11/01/2021], 0),
  [12/01/2021] = COALESCE([12/01/2021], 0),
  [01/01/2022] = COALESCE([01/01/2022], 0),
  [02/01/2022] = COALESCE([02/01/2022], 0),
  [03/01/2022] = COALESCE([03/01/2022], 0)
FROM agg PIVOT (SUM(c) FOR m IN (
  [10/01/2021],[11/01/2021],[12/01/2021],
  [01/01/2022],[02/01/2022],[03/01/2022]
)) AS p;
```

To get there:

```
DECLARE @thisMonth date, @firstMonth date;
SET @thisMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), 1);
SET @firstMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, -5, @thisMonth);

DECLARE @col1 nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @col2 nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @sql  nvarchar(max) = N';WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT ID, Name, m = CONVERT(char(10), 
      DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(SalesDate), Month(SalesDate), 1), 101)
  FROM dbo.JetSales
  WHERE SalesDate >= @firstMonth
),
agg AS
(
  SELECT ID, Name, m, c = COUNT(*)
  FROM src GROUP BY ID, Name, m
)
SELECT ID, Name,';

;WITH m(m) AS 
(
  SELECT @firstMonth
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m) FROM m
  WHERE m < @thisMonth
),
x(x) AS 
(
  SELECT QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10), m, 101)) FROM m
)
SELECT 
  @col1 += STRING_AGG(CONCAT(N'
', x, N' = COALESCE(', x, ',0)'),N','),
  @col2 += STRING_AGG(x, N',
')
FROM x;

SET @sql += @col1 + N'
FROM agg PIVOT (SUM(c) FOR m IN (' 
+ @col2 + N'
)) AS p;';

SELECT @sql;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@firstMonth date', @firstMonth;
```

Another fiddle here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c85d3bb1c0c4fec1b83b9d8be739e745)

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I think the issue I'm having is when I run your pivot query, it's saying that 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built in  function name, I'm not sure if SSMS is too old or too new. Can you please help me understand if there's a replacement I can use to substitute with 'STRING_AGG'?

Comment: @mgh did you try the first query? Did it work? Can you use that? When you posted the question, I asked what version of SQL Server you’re using. You should always specify when asking your question. Most people will assume you’re using a modern, supported version of SQL Server. This has nothing to do with SSMS. Run `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: Apparently, I'm using 2016 version... also, i tried the first one but my table is actually a cte and it doesn't recognize my cte...

Comment: @mgh If you post your actual code somewhere that demonstrates how you get your data from a table into the CTE, then we may be able to help you adapt the code. Otherwise the answer is incomplete because it was written against incomplete info.